# How to delete Linux partition from computer?

Tags: linux, windows-vista, partitioning

I am running Windows Vista and Linux on my computer. I want to delete Linux. I know how to get this far:

- Log into Windows Vista
- right-click on My Computer
- Click Manage
- Choose Disk Management listed under Storage

From there I see all of the partitions listed. My guess is the partitions without a label (such as C or D) are the Linux partitions (I see three).

What I am particularly concerned with is, after I delete the Linux partitions from within Windows Vista,

- must I do anything else to make sure that Windows will still continue to work fine?
- are there additional steps to reclaim the memory?
- can I re-install Linux in the future?

If someone has actually done this successfully, please mention so in your response.

Comment: Not going to downvote, but I am going to cast a close vote. Please post on the correct board next time (we'll move this one to the correct one in a moment)

Comment: Do you know if you are using GRUB to boot? Was Linux installed after Windows?

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen Will you please explain why?

Comment: @Konsol: Because this isn't a programming related question, and Stack Overflow is only for those.

Comment: @bcurcio yes: GNU GRUB versopm 1/99~rc1-13ubuntu3

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen I saw this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350331/questions-with-partitioning-in-sql-server-2005?rq=1 .

Comment: That should probably go in ServerFault (did it exist two years ago? I think it did)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After I delete the linux partitions from within Windows Vista, must I do anything else to make use that windows will still continue to work fine?

Yes, you need the Windows Recovery Disk to restore the bootloader since you are using GRUB now. This is very important, your computer will become unusable once you erase the GRUB partition. You might want to google "restore MBR windows vista" before erasing anything.

> After I delete the linux partitions from within Windows Vista, are there additional steps to reclaim the memory?

They are empty partitions. If you want to use them, you will have to format them from the disk management menu.

> After I delete the linux partitions from within Windows Vista, can I re-install linux in the future?

Yes, installing linux is always possible if you have enough space.

Comment: Thanks. I try to up vote but apparently I have too few credits. I found this link: http://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/fix-mbr-xp-vista/